# Is it possible to define the date and time format in a DateTime object?

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have a desktop app (WinForm) that sends data to a remote WebService. This is working fine, but the web service owners are claiming that the DateTime that I send is in `mm/dd/YYYY` format and they need `dd/mm/YYYY`

Is there any way to change that?

I don't need to convert to string, the web service needs a DateTime object to be sent.

Edit:

I found the problem, I was using

```
Date.Parse(Datos(1))' Datos(1) = 2023-11-7 16:15:48 -
```

Datos is a list of strings.

Now I'm trying to use this

```
Dim DummyDate As New DateTime
DummyDate = Date.ParseExact(Datos(1), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

But I get an exception

"The string cannot be recognized as a valid DateTime value."

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The `DateTime` object itself has no format.  When you send data to the remote webservice, your `DateTime` object is being formatted as a string.  Without showing debugging details of how you're making the call to the web service, it's impossible for us to answer this question.  Lastly, the _correct_ format to send to a remote web service is usually ISO-8601, which uses `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint That's what I was thinking, because if I try to get only the month I get 11, which is correct, but they say that I'm sending month 7 and day 11

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I just updated the post.

Comment: It's really unclear now whether the problem is actually about how you're sending values, or how you're parsing strings into `DateTime` values to start with. It sounds like it's actually the latter, which is entirely orthogonal to what your original post talked about.

Comment: This code shows you trying to parse `Datos(1)` as an _input_ to a specific format, but that's **backwards**. You need to show us the code where you write or serialize the existing (unformatted!) DateTime value for _output_.

Comment: In your `ParseExact` call, "dd" means that the day must always have two digits but your value does not have the single-digit day value padded with a "0". That means that you should be using "yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss" to parse that value. You need to consider whether the same applies to the other parts, e.g. the month and hour.

Comment: @jmcilhinney But then, if I use a single d in a couple of days it will fail again because it will be 2 digits to decode. I was thinking that dd means up to 2 digits. What about the number separator like slashes"/" and "-" should be the same?

Comment: No, it won't fail. If you had read the relevant documentation, as you should have well before now, then you would know that. "d" works with single- or double-digit days, whereas "dd" only works with double-digit days, requiring anything less than 10 to be padded with a leading zero. We shouldn't have to explain things that are easy to find for yourself in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

No, a `DateTime` value doesn't *have* a format. Think of it like an integer - and integer isn't "in" decimal or hex, but you can format or parse an integer in a particular format. Exactly the same is true for `DateTime`.

We don't know anything about how you're forming your request (and it's pretty weird that they need dd/MM/yyyy instead of an ISO-8601 format of yyyy-MM-dd), but you can specify a format (and culture) in `DateTime.ToString`. If you're not creating the request manually, I'd *expect* there to be ways of configuring whatever is serializing your request to serialize `DateTime` values in a specific format.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, because if I try to get only the month I get 11, which is correct, but they say that I'm sending month 7 and day 11.

Comment: I just updated the post.

Comment: @E_Blue: With the update to the post, we're still missing a *lot* of information. It sounds like it's really nothing to do with the web service at all, but about how you're parsing data you receive from some list of strings which you hadn't mentioned before. That's why it's always really important to give more context and ideally a [mcve]. Please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints

Comment: I'm requesting data from a MySQL server and formatting all the fields to fulfill the remote server protocol standards; to do so I use this date_format(from_unixtime(timestamp),'%Y/%m/%e %k:%i:%s') as 'timestamp'; because the date is in unix time format in my data base.

Comment: @E_Blue: This shouldn't be in comments, it should be in the post to start with, including sample data. (It's not clear why you don't just get the unix timestamp and convert it in your C# code, rather than formatting it in SQL and then parsing it in C#...)